# How do we run a Python script in Atom editor?

Tags: python, atom-editor

How do we run a Python script in Atom editor? Please see screenshot below with errors:
[Below I was testing if i can run python in Atom editor. I have also ran the (**c:\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate base**)command in Anaconda prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fr3uu.png)

Comment: Seems like you are trying to run a command line program in a python shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Atom built-in terminal, you are first typing in "python" without any file arguments, and such bringing you into the Python Interactive Prompt, include the name of your file (num.py).

The SyntaxError you're getting is because your trying to run "python num.py" as code instead of a CMD command.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response guys, now I see my mistake.

Comment: There is no built-in terminal in Atom

Comment: Then what is OP using in the attached photo?

Comment: @NjabuloMdunge Would you please consider marking my answer as the accepted one just to raise my Reputation on here since I don't post much? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @HarryKearney answer, there are a number of packages that will easily run scripts. For example, [run-in-terminal](https://github.com/pohmelie/run-in-terminal) allows you to press F5 to open a terminal or command prompt window running the python script. Some other options to do similar things are: [atom-python-run](https://atom.io/packages/atom-python-run), [atom-runner](https://atom.io/packages/atom-runner), [script](https://atom.io/packages/script) to run code directly in atom and several others you can find in the [package repository](https://atom.io/packages). Choosing one of these and installing it will probably make it a lot easy if you will be running python scripts frequently.